# Why does 'git checkout -b $$' switch to branch '36415' instead of '$$'?

Tags: git

Why is Git converting `$$` to `36415` when I run `'git checkout -b $$'`? It works fine when I use just one dollar sign.

Comment: *Git* isn't. Your *shell* is doing that. Try `echo $$`, `wc $$`, `printf "I said $$\n"`, and so on.

Comment: I see what you mean! I got the same result in terminal. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bshell%5D+double+dollar